# Calculated List does not update after NotifyPropertyChanged WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list object that is updated regularly inside of a model class. I want to propagate those changes from my model to my view using a calculated property.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Zebra MyZebra { get; } = new Zebra();

    public IList<Stripe> StripeCollection => MyZebra.Stripes;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        MyZebra.StripesChanged += (sender, args) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StripeCollection"));
    }
}
```

I am bound to the ItemsSource of a WPF object like so:

`ItemsSource="{Binding StripeCollection}"`

When the event triggers, it does not update my bindings. And when I enter a breakpoint before I trigger the PropertyChanged event, I see that my collection has indeed updated how I want it to both in the Model and in the ViewModel.

If I change this line:

`public IList<Stripe> StripeCollection => MyZebra.GetStripes;`

to:

`public IList<Stripe> StripeCollection => new List<Stripe>(MyZebra.GetStripes);`

the binding does update. However, I am not interested in copying the list every time the stripes change. (Apparently Zebras change stripes very often).

The List inside of MyZebras is updated frequently, but the list object itself is never reassigned.

Why is this happening? And is there a way to trigger updates without reconstructing the list?

Comment: What is the actual type of MyZebra.StripesChanged?

Comment: `public event EventHandler StripesChanged;`

Comment: I copied and pasted the wrong bit, I ment to ask what is the actual type of the collection `MyZebra.Stripes`

Comment: Another way of doing this is to take a look at `ObservableCollection` instead of `IList`

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I'm unable to change the implementation of Zebra, unfortunately.

Comment: @etberg But you can change implementation of ViewModel, or?

Comment: @Rekshino Yes, of course. But if I cast the Zebra's list to Observable collection I lose the reference don't I?

Comment: Will be StripesChanged fired on each change? So you could probably apply the change to the observable collection in handler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it be recognized, that the value of `StripeCollection` (reference to MyZebra.Stripes) didn't changed, so despite PropertyChanged notification you see no changes.
One possible solution you have already found.

Another one to avoid generation of new objects is to set `StripeCollection` in `StripesChanged` handler temporary to null. For you can do it you have to rewrite `StripeCollection`.

```
public IList<Stripe> StripeCollection {
  get { return _stripeCollection; }
  set {
    _stripeCollection = value;
     PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(StripeCollection)));
  }
} 
private IList<Stripe> _stripeCollection=MyZebra.Stripes;

MyZebra.StripesChanged += (sender, args) => {var tmpCol=StripeCollection; StripeCollection=null; StripeCollection=tmpCol;};
```

Consequence is that your UI-Control will be refreshed(whole list).

Better solution is to use ObservableCollection as Jordy van Eijk has advised.

**UPDATE**:

There is one more solution with `CollectionView`:

```
public ICollectionView StripeCollection
{
    get { return _stripeCollection; }
    set
    {
        _stripeCollection = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(StripeCollection)));
    }
}
private ICollectionView _stripeCollection =new CollectionView(MyZebra.Stripes);
MyZebra.StripesChanged += (sender, args) => {StripeCollection.Refresh();};
```

**One more solution** is to use ObservableCollection for `StripeCollection` and maintain/synchronize it with `MyZebra.Stripes` in handler.

Comment: This solution ends up reducing performance from what I have currently. The bottleneck is WPF refreshing the list completely when it is reassigned (how I am currently doing it). This solution makes the UI refresh the list twice. First when it is null, then the next to after it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the setter of StripeCollection you need to notify the view by firing the property changed after setting the property.

```
private IList<Stripe> _stripeCollection;
public IList<Stripe> StripeCollection {
  get { return _stripeCollection; }
  set {
    _stripeCollection = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
} //=> MyZebra.Stripes
```

This way you can notify the view that the property has changed. If you want to do this from another point you nee to call the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StripeCollection))`

And if you want to notify the view that StripeCollection has been set from inside the Zebra object. [You can use EventAggregation / Publish and Subscribe](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23314.using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models.aspx)